# How to implement window closing (display: none) when scrolling the page?

Tags: jquery

How to implement window closing (display: none) when scrolling the page?.
The page is made in the form of a slider and because of this, such a record does not work. https://oleggood22.github.io/orel.github.io/

```
<script>
  mousewheel(function() {
    $("elem.id").css("display","none");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? Where is `mousewheel()` defined?

Comment: did you mean `$(elem.id).css("display","none");` ? `"elem.id"` won't be valid because it is a literal string when it looks like you are trying to reference whichever element is active with `elem.id`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Here is a page that should help you form good questions as you work here more.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

A common method to handle situations like these, is to use the callback functions provided by the plugins. You should be able to find the callback info in the plugin docs.

You would have to do the following,

1. Provide a common class for all your modals

   `<div id="myModal" class="modal common-class">`

   and

   `<div id="myModal_2" class="modal_2 common-class">`
2. Hide any modal using the relevant callback(in this case 'beforeMove')

   `$(".main").onepage_scroll({
       sectionContainer: "section",
       responsiveFallback: 600,
       loop: true,
       beforeMove: function(index) {
        $('.common-class').css('display','none');
       }
     });`